# A job must execute each monday. Monday was a holiday, so must execute tuesday. How do this?

Tags: .net, quartz-scheduler, cron

I have a job that must execute each monday. This job run in a server, in a home office. People work here from 8:00 AM to 6PM. The computer is off the rest of the time.

This is expressed in a CRON:

```
0 0 12 ? * MON *
```

And this is the schedule:

```
1.  Monday, June 25, 2012 12:00 PM
2.  Monday, July 2, 2012 12:00 PM
3.  Monday, July 9, 2012 12:00 PM
4.  Monday, July 16, 2012 12:00 PM
5.  Monday, July 23, 2012 12:00 PM
```

However, June 25 is a holiday. I need to be sure that the job is executed in tuesday 8:00 AM (when the server wakeup).

This is important because other task running in the day depend in that the first one happend. Also, the result are uploaded to a remote server, and is necessary to have the results without wait until next week.

The software that do this is in .NET and use quartz.net with CRONs to express the executions.

So I wonder how solve this problem with reliability and without user intervention. I tough in have a kind of checklist or log-ahead where I mark if the expect task happened, but can't articulate in computer terms how do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well obviously you must have some data file, (or maybe some decided algorithm) that can tell you when to run your app.

Either you'll write it manually, or query it from somewhere.

After doing so, just compare the current date to the list of dates you created.
If today's date is on the list, and you haven't marked you app ran already, run it now.

Have a nice day.